# how to delete all the subfolders except one subfolder in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

I have directory structure like this in  unix
A is parent directoty--> B C D are subdirectories--->B directory having X Y Z directories.

I want to delete all subdirectories except  X subdirectory.

I already tried this way..

```
find * -name 'X' -prune -o -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
```

This command  deletes all the directory.What would be the code to solve my problem in `unix`?

Comment: move the files you want out of X to another directory, remove all the subfolders, re-create X then put all the files back in...

Comment: Do you want to end with only `A/B/X` or with `A/X` ?

Comment: I need both solutuons, can you pls add both.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if your directory structure is: `a/b/c/`

`mv a/b/c/ .` - will move directory `c/` to your pwd `.` (present working directory)

then

`rm -r a/` - will recursively ***remove*** `a/` AND all subdirectories (i.e. `b/`)

These can be executed in one line with: `mv a/b/c/ . ;rm -r a/` however, I would recommend executing separately, so you can check to make sure you have the contents of your target properly moved before recursively removing the other subdirectories.

Note: instead of using `.` to specify your pwd, you could also specify a some other directory path.

And last but not least, the unix manual pages are a nice resource if you are unsure about how certain commands work. To use them, type `man <command>` for example `man mv` or `man rm`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have write permissions for the directory X you can use the permissions

Finish with only A/B/X (and subdirs of X)

```
find . -type d -name X -exec chmod -w {} \;
rm -fr A 2>/dev/null
find . -type d -name X -exec chmod +w {} \;
```

Finish with A/X (and only have one subdir named X) you need an a step

```
find . -type d -name X -exec mv {} A/ \; -quit
chmod -w A/X
rm -fr A
chmod +w A/X
```

Comment: i am executing first command, geting like this type error : Operation not permitted.

Comment: In that case you are not the owner of the files. Try the solution of @Jagawag.